# Spring data mongo: Projection not working when path includes a key of a HashMap

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

### Problem

When I try to project a value which is inside a `java.util.Map` then I get below exception. But when I run the generated shell query in roboMongo then It works. I would be very grateful if somebody could point out the problem.

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: No property Germany found on com.nntn.corona.snapshot.repo.model.StatWithDelta!
```

### Query Code In Java

**spring boot parent:** 2.0.5.RELEASE

```
Criteria matchCriteria = Criteria.where("timestamp").gte(startDate);
        MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(matchCriteria);
        SortOperation sort = sort(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "timestamp"));

        // @formatter:off
        ProjectionOperation projection = project()
                .andExpression("timestamp").as("timestamp")
                .andExpression("countries.germany.total").as("total")
                .andExpression("countries.germany.today").as("today");
        // @formatter:on

        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(match, sort,projection);

        AggregationResults<Document> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, SnapshotEntry.class,
                Document.class);
        return result.getMappedResults();
```

### Data Model

**Java representation**

```
@Document(collection = "snpashots")
public class SnapshotEntry {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private DateTime timestamp;

    private Map<String, StatWithDelta> countries;
    private StatEntity total;
    private StatEntity today;
    private String source;
    private String previousRecordId;

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class StatWithDelta {
        private StatEntity total;
        private StatEntity today;
    }

}
```

**Json representation**

```
{
    "_id" : "21-03-2020",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2020-03-21T09:26:00.965Z"),
    "countries" : {
        "germany" : {
            "total" : {
                "born" : NumberLong(81008),
                "dead" : NumberLong(3255),
                "sick" : NumberLong(30000)
            },
            "today" : {
                "born" : NumberLong(50),
                "dead" : NumberLong(10),
                "sick" : NumberLong(12)
            }
        }
    },
    "_class" : "com.nntn.snapshot.repo.model.SnapshotEntry"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in [TypedAggregation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/TypedAggregation.html). This is a special aggregation where Spring holds information of the input aggregation type.

To avoid it, use raw aggregation (as if you run in MongoDB shell) this way:

```
AggregationResults<SnapshotEntry> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, 
            mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(SnapshotEntry.class),
            SnapshotEntry.class);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Valijon. That solved the issue. :)